# batch from exe from batch from console - output in the same console

Tags: c#, batch-file, console-application

I have an exe (C# application which has both gui and console output for some logging) which launches a batch file. Sometimes I launch this exe from another batch file. The scenario with problems is this:

```
- I open a console (let's call it the initial console);
- I start the batch file 1 from that console;
- batch1 launches the exe;
- exe launches batch file 2.
```

The problem is that the exe starts a new console for batch2 although its own logging output is written in the initial console. I want also the output of batch2 in the initial console. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Grant that you can edit the "exe" program, what you need to do is "hide" the 2nd console (batch) and redirect it's output into a string, you need to do somethink like below:

```
    string myoutput = string.empty;
    Process process = new Process();
    ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C c:\test.bat");
    startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
    process.StartInfo = startinfo;
    process.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) => myoutput += args.Data;
    process.Start();
    process.BeginOutputReadLine();
    process.WaitForExit();
//Use myoutput as you like :)
```

*EDIT*: I cannot reproduce your issue... maybe you can try this other way:

```
Process process = new Process();
        ProcessStartInfo startinfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe", @"/C c:\test.bat");
        startinfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startinfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        process.StartInfo = startinfo;
        //process.OutputDataReceived += (s, args) => myoutput += args.Data;
        process.Start();
string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

string output_ERR = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

Comment: Well, it works and it doesn't. I have now the messages from batch2 in the initial console but appear only error ones. No "echo"s, no "dir"s etc.

Comment: Mh.... try remove "startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;" i think now the echo will be redirected, but probably you se again a flashing batch window.... idk if process had a "hide" attributo that you can set to hide it.

Comment: No, it is not ok:
[2018/07/17 15:26:59.937][Error  ][Module]: The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams.

Comment: Edit answer with another try

Comment: I have tried to remove "startinfo.UseShellExecute = false;" and I got at runtime the error:
"The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams."

Comment: With the second code I see no output at all from batch2. Plus, it waits for batch2 to finish and I don't want it. (In the first piece of code I have commented the WaitForExit)

Comment: Ok, if you cannot wait the batch you need to use the first code... idk why not show the echos, i try to do some tests